# Regex to repair malformed XML attributes, removing spaces in tags

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regexp-replace

I've been unfortunate to have come accross alot of malformed XML.
I cannot get the correct regex to remove 2 spaces inside the attribute/key.

My current regex also checks to see if there is a valid "=" attribute.

XML attributes have to have a value or / and just one key.

for example

```
<ImValid></ImValid>
<Im not Valid></Im not Valid>
<ImValid with="somthing"></ImValid>
```

Here is my malformed XML:

```
<Addresses>
  <Address>
    <Delivery id>123123</Delivery id>
    <Delivery Code Id>123123</Delivery Code Id>
    <Full Name>Agent Smith</Full Name>
  </Address>
  <Address>
    <Delivery id>12322123</Delivery id>
    <Delivery Code Id>12zz3123</Delivery Code Id>
    <Full Name>Mr Anderson</Full Name>
  </Address>
<Addresses>
```

I'm trying to repair it using regex.

```
AstringVar => Regex.Replace(AstringVar , @"(?=<[^=]+?>)(?=</?\w+\s+\w+)(<.*?)(\s+)(.*?>)", @"$1$3", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

This Will Change This

```
<Full Name>Mr Anderson</Full Name>
```

This

```
<FullName>Mr Anderson</FullName>
```

Improving  .. But also missing the last space..

```
<DeliveryCode Id>12zz3123</DeliveryCode Id>
```

Ok...i could run it twice ... but..
that seems ugly...
how would I be able to get both 1 space and 2 spaces whilst also avoiding the values
Thanks to any regex heros who can help ...!

Here it is on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dVs51I/3)https://regex101.com/r/dVs51I/3

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your pattern, you want to:

- `<[^=]+?>` Make sure that there is no `=` between `<...>`
- `(?=</?\w+\s+\w+)` Make sure that the first char is a word char after `<` or `</` and that there is at least a whitespace char and a second word character
- `(<.*?)(\s+)(.*?>)` Match 1 or more whitespace chars between `<...>`

The issue here is that `(<.*?)(\s+)(.*?>)` will have only a single match.

Also when you have `<test ></test >` you will not match the last space as there is only a single word.

---

**Note** that this is for the given examples and is not fool proof to the versatility of xml.

Using C# you can make use of an infinite quantifier in a lookbehind assertion to get multiple matches.

```
(?<=</?\s*\w[^<>=]*)\s+(?=[^=<>]*>)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert that to the left is

  - `</?` Match either `<` or `</`
  - `\s*\w` Match optional whitespace chars followed by a single word char
  - `[^<>=]*` Optionally repeat matching any character except `<` `>` `=`
- `)` Close the lookbehind assertion
- `\s+` Match 1 or more whitespace characters
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert that to the right is

  - `[^=<>]*` Optionally repeat matching any character except `<` `>` `=`
- `>)` Match `>`

See a [C# regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sdjs1u/1).